# Vue project with or without Babel?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue CLI to create a Vue 2.0 project and one of the options is using Babel.  I understand Babel is a transpiler but what exactly does it do?  I created a project with it and another without it and I don't see the difference so what exactly is the pro/con of it ?  I can't see offhand what it is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Babel is a transpiler. It transpiles your JavaScript code to one or more taget browsers, that does not support the lastest fetures. You will not see any difference, if using a newer browser.

Babal usually only makes sense if you need to support older browsers, like IE 11 or browsers from before 2017.

Comment: "only makes sense if you need to support older browsers" -- this made me understand the need for it.  Thanks!

Comment: so if the application is used by staffs only, we can use latest versions of browsers, without babel supports, but it is required when users are not staffs.

Comment: @DanielYang Babel is only "required" if you want to support older browsers. You don't need to. You could ask your users to upgrade their browser, if it's too old. It would be easier for you, and do them a favour.